# Using a Frame class in a Tk class in Python tkinter

Tags: python, class, tkinter

In the below example, I am trying to use Frame1() in MainW(). I tried many variations of the below code. The problem is that the frame object color and rowspan are not changing at all. I know there is a problem in terms of using Frame1() in MainW(). Can someone point out the error?

```
from tkinter import *

class Frame1(Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent):
            Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="red")
            self.parent = parent
            self.widgets()
        def widgets(self):
            self.text = Text(self)
            self.text.insert(INSERT, "Hello World\t")
            self.text.insert(END, "This is the first frame")
            self.text.grid(row=0, column=0)


class MainW(Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.mainWidgets()
    def mainWidgets(self):
        self.label = Label(self, text="Main window label")
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.window = Frame1(self)
        self.window.grid(row=0, column=10, rowspan=2)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = MainW(None)
    app.mainloop()
```

Here is the output which is not what I want. I need the frame's background red and rowspan to be 1:
[image]

Thank you

Comment: what color ? red ? You put `Text()` and you can't see frame color. `Text()` isn't transparent - it has own color.

Comment: what problem do you have with grid ? Cell in grid has no width and height till you put widget in this cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't see frame color because you put widget which fills all frame.

If you add margins (`padx`, `pady`) then you can see frame color.

```
self.text.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)
```

You can't see `rowspan` because you have empty `cell` is second row. Empty cell has no width and height. Add Label in second row and will see how `rowspan` works.

```
from tkinter import *

class Frame1(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="red")
        self.parent = parent
        self.widgets()

    def widgets(self):
        self.text = Text(self)
        self.text.insert(INSERT, "Hello World\t")
        self.text.insert(END, "This is the first frame")
        self.text.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20) # margins


class MainW(Tk):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.mainWidgets()

    def mainWidgets(self):

        self.label1 = Label(self, text="Main window label", bg="green")
        self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.label2 = Label(self, text="Main window label", bg="yellow")
        self.label2.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.window = Frame1(self)
        self.window.grid(row=0, column=10, rowspan=2)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = MainW(None)
    app.mainloop()
```

[image]